# Python words generator

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, cpu-word

I'm currently trying to run a program where the user inputs a word and then after they input the first word, the program will ask if they want to continue putting words. Once the user replies "no", the program will generate the list of words that has been input. I seem to be having trouble calling the array for my code below:

```
def word():
    w1 = input("Please enter a word: ")
    group = []
    group.append(w1)
    decide = input("Do you want to continue? yes/no: ")
    if (decide == "yes"):
        return -1
    elif (decide == "no"):
        return 1


while (True):
    crit = word()
    if (crit == -1):
        continue
    elif (crit == 1):
        print("words are: ", group)
        break
```

How I can make this work properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "trouble calling the array"?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to pass the `list` into the function:

```py
def word(group):
    w1 = input("Please enter a word: ")
    group.append(w1)
    decide = input("Do you want to continue? yes/no: ")
    return decide == "yes"

group = []
while True:
    crit = word(group)
    if crit:
        continue
    else:
        print("words are: ", group)
        break
```

Comment: Please don't use the previously accepted answer as your code.

Answer (score 0):

The array ‘group’ is defined inside the function word(). This means if the function is returned, the list ‘group’ disappears also.

You can either

1. Use global variable

Define group outside the function (in this case, at the top) and use that global list inside the function. I.e. add the line
`global group` in the first line of the function.

However, using global variable when not needed is not so recommandable.

2. Define group list outside the function and pass it to the function as an argument

Instead of `def word()`, use `def word(group)` and pass the list to the function when calling the function.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Answer (score 0):

```
group = []

def word():
    w1 = input("Please enter a word: ")
    group.append(w1)
    decide = input("Do you want to continue? yes/no: ")
    if (decide == "yes"):
        return -1
    elif (decide == "no"):
        return 1


while (True):
    crit = word()
    if (crit == -1):
        continue
    elif (crit == 1):
        print("words are: ", group)
        break
```

The variable `group` is not available outside the function.

A variable created outside of a function is global and can be used by anyone.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.